# How to add additional parameters to the urllib2 opener

Tags: python, browser, http-headers, urllib2, bots

I found this website:
https://panopticlick.eff.org/
That basically gives you some information of your browser. And it raised a question. so i was trying to create an urlllib2 opener and only thing I did is changed it's user-agent:
so my opener looks like that:

```
class URLOpener():      
    def opener(self,user_agent):
        cj=cookielib.CookieJar()
        #Process Hadlers
        opener=urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
        opener.addheaders=[
                        ('User-Agent', user_agent),
                        ('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'),
                        ('Accept-Language', 'en-gb,en;q=0.5'),
                        ('Accept-Charset', 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7'),
                        ('Keep-Alive', '115'),
                        ('Connection', 'keep-alive'),
                        ('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0'),
                    ]
        return opener
```

My question is how can I add something like this to my URLOpener:

1. Browser Plugin Details
2. Time Zone
3. Screen Size and Color Depth
4. System Fonts
5. Limited supercookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

Most of those things are not passed by your browser to the web server. The reason that panopticlick can display those values is that it uses Javascript to access them.

You can see this for yourself. In Chrome or firefox open up the network tab in the developer console and look at the actual headers that are being sent when you make a request to a website.

Comment: So basically,you saying is that if in my website I will try to check 'Browser Plugin Details' of a client and will get None, this means,this is not a human?

Comment: I am saying that the Browser Plugin Details are being sent using Javascript and not as HTTP headers.

Comment: Got you. However do you know any libraries I can use to kinda simulate  it?

Comment: I do not, but you could look at the source code of panopticlick and see how it is doing it.